# Using one button click method to handle all clicks

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

lets say I have a bunch of buttons like this

```
<Button x:Name="EditButton" Style="{StaticResource EditAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"  Foreground="White"/>
<Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Style="{StaticResource RemoveAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click" Foreground="White"/>
```

and in my `Click` method is there a way to have all the clicks use that one method and use a few if statements to handle what button was clicked or do I have to make separate methods for each button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single button click event if you want.  That's entirely appropriate.

Note that if you're going to do that you probably shouldn't have a whole bunch of ifs to try to determine which button this is for.  If you're going to share a handler it should mean that you don't need to do that.

If a portion of the click handler is the same and a portion different it may be preferable to have different handlers for each button, but to have them all call a single method to handle the common functionality.

Comment: How would I find out what button initiated the callback though? I didnt see anything in the callback method that would give me the name of the calling button. I am relatively new to c# so forgive me on the basic questions

Comment: @tyczj Generally you shouldn't need it; if you do it's a strong sign that you probably shouldn't be sharing an event handler.  That said, it's passed as the `sender` parameter.